# How to calculate the interqaurtile range of an array where you know the array and the array length

Tags: java, algorithm, average

I keep getting a null pointer exception on line 9 and if I change it slightly the program only returns 0

i tried using an array that stores each individual result however i have now moved on to a data dictionary format that should reduce memory costs

```java
package footballPredictor;

class Team
{
    private static int[] scored = new int[10];
    private int gamesPlayed;
    private String name;

    Team(String name)
    {
      this.name = name;
      gamesPlayed = 0;
    }

    String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    int[] getScored()
    { 
       return scored; 
    }

    int getGamesPlayed()
    { 
       return gamesPlayed; 
    }

    void addValue(int value)
    {
        if (value > 9)
            scored[9]++;
        else
            scored[value]++;
        gamesPlayed++;
    }

    int calculateValue(int[] results, int games)
    {
        int lowerBound = (int) Math.round(games / 4);
        int higherBound = (int) Math.round(3 * games / 4);
        int remaining = higherBound - lowerBound;
        int total = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int gameAmount = remaining;
        while(remaining>0)
            if (results[i] < lowerBound) {
                lowerBound -= results[i];
                i++;
            } else if (results[i] > lowerBound && (results[i] - lowerBound < remaining)) {
                total = (results[i] - lowerBound) * i;
                remaining -= (results[i] - lowerBound);
                i++;
            } else if (remaining > results[i]) {
                total += results[i] * i;
                remaining -= results[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                remaining += results[i] * remaining;
            }
        return (total/(gameAmount+1));
    }
}
```

The code of calculate value should return the interquartile mean of the array that has come in. however before it only returns 0 and now it doesnt work at all

Comment: which one is line 9?

Comment: I meant this one, if (results[i] < lowerBound) {

Comment: Most likely your `i` goes out of bounds. Adjusting `remaining` and the bounds with the values in `result` looks suspicious. What does your data look like? Could you give an example input in the question?

Comment: check the input parameter from where you are calling method calculateValue(),you would be passing null as first parameter for array. If not please add complete code.